# TestNG not executing tests from command line

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, testng

I have a problem executing TestNG from command line. Everything works perfect when I invoke it directly from IntellIJ but when I try to do this from command line I'm constantly gettinng:

```
===============================================
Parallel Tests Suite
Total tests run: 0, Passes: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] No tests found. Nothing was run
```

I've tried every solution from: [TestNG not running tests in testing suite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457326/testng-not-running-tests-in-testing-suite) but still nothing is working for me.

My test classes are extending base class where driver is iniciated. Once I've tried to not use inheritance but simple driver calling (driver is static) from base class and with `verbose` option something more appeared in output:

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
```

But this way I'm getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` in every test class invoked so I guess it's not a solution.

My `testng.xml` file looks like:

```
<suite name="Parallel Tests Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="1" verbose ="5">

    <test name="TestExample" >
        <classes>
            <class name = "package.ExampleClass"/>
            ....
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

I'm trying to execute tests by:

```
Java -cp "...\ProjectName\lib\*;...\ProjectName\target\test-classes" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

In `lib` directory there are:

- `jcommander`,
- `selenium-java-client-driver`,
- `selenium-server-standalone`,
- `testng`

jars.

In `test-classes` there are `.class` files.

Stucture of my project is like:

- `ProjectName`

  - `src`

    - `test`

      - `java`

        - `package`

          - `tests`
          - `pages`
          - ...
  - `target`

    - `test-classes`
    - ...
  - `testng.xml`
  - ...

Would really appreciate some help with this. Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896791/how-to-run-testng-from-command-line/49673326#49673326

Comment: I've also seen this post but there is nothing helpful for me. Thanks anyway.